# Repetitive search using Selenium and Python. And give me ones that they have no results

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, web, form-submit

I wanna enter `Samsung *** Plus` in a search field then press the search button in a website. (Repetitively)

This site doesn't have any captcha, doesn't go to another page for search results.
Each time in this loop instead of these three stars I want a letter or a number to be submitted.
This means it searches 46,656 times. `((25+10).(25+10).(25+10))`
And print the ones that result in a `"Not found!" paragraph`.

PS. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Hi, what site are you using? If you can share the url we can have a look at the underlying delivery method to see if there are and other alternative to selenium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it would be best to provide more information (including the URL, specific code you've tried, etc).

First just set up your webdriver and page

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('www.yoururl.com')
```

Now we will find the elements needed. You can use whatever method you would like but I'll use name.

```
search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('searchBoxName')
search_button = driver.find_element_by_name('searchButtonName')
```

Now we will loop through the different numbers of your search while returning the result. This is the beginning of the loop

```
for i in range(46656): #based on the number you gave
    search_box.send_keys('Samsung {} Plus'.format(i))
    search_button.click()
```

Returning the results is a bit tricky, considering you didn't really give much info. There are 2 main ways to go about this.

Option 1: Find the element responsible for giving the search result and grab the `.text` property. Here's the for loop with that example.

```
for i in range(46656): #based on the number you gave
        search_box.send_keys('Samsung {} Plus'.format(i))
        search_button.click()
        result = driver.find_element_by_name('result')
        if result.text == 'Not Found!': 
            print("Samsung {} Plus: Not Found".format(i))
```

Option 2: If there is a certain element only present when there are no results, you can try to locate that element and use it's presence to mark the absence of results. You can also do this backwards if there is a specific element present only when there ARE results.

```
for i in range(46656): #based on the number you gave
        search_box.send_keys('Samsung {} Plus'.format(i))
        search_button.click()
        try: #look for the element that is present when there are no results
            no_results = driver.find_element_by_name('noResults')
            print("Samsung {} Plus: Not found!".format(i))
        except NoSuchElementException: #if element is not found, there are results
            pass
```

If you choose Option 2, you will need to add this line in your code:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
So perfect and so simple explanation!
Very helpful!